# Missing notifications from top indicator

Tags: 16.04, notification, notify-osd

I am missing new notifications. If I try to raise and lower the volume or brightness, the classic top right hand indicator no longer appears.

If I try `notify-send test`, then this test notification appears:

[image: test notification]

I tried `sudo apt-get --reinstall install notify-osd` but it does not work the same.

Comment: Did you find a fix yet? If not, can you please tell me what you did to trigger this result?

Comment: @J.Rahman , the notifications disappeared following an attempt to create a desktop environment. After I removed the desktop environment I returned to Unity. For general notifications I resolved with xfce4-notifyd and for the volume notification I use xfce4-volumed , but I did not find a way for the brightness notification.

Comment: It might be caused due to clashing notification applications used by different desktops. Xubuntu-desktop uses `xfce4-notifyd` for example, instead of `notify-osd`.  Try choosing one and purging the other.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe , I tried as you suggested, I ran `sudo apt-get purge notify-osd` and rebooted, but still nothing.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Are you missing all notifications in general or just the brightness indicator? If it is the latter case, try using the keyboard shortcut to increase/decrease brightness. You should see the indicator. I cannot comment on other desktops, but on Xubuntu I can confirm that the brightness indicator does not work (as of v16.04) while changing brightness through scrolling on the battery icon.

Comment: This is from dunst. Remove it